# What is a good 3D library for Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, 3d

I need a 3D library that works well with Flex... NOT Flex Builder - the free Flex SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Papervision 3D](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/index.html). Note Flex Builder is an IDE that internally uses the Flex SDK (and sort of simplifies life for you). There is nothing that stops you from using *any* library with Flex SDK (if you know how to add them to your project etc).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried Away3D, but it seemed like a REALLY complicated library.